# java inter thread communication created in different context using wait() and notify() VS semaphore which one is better

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

This program prints even and odd using two thread , with semaphore it is working fine . I tried to use wait() and notify() using synchronized monitor as per comment so which one is better code without wait and notify but less inter thread communication vs message passing using wait and notify.

```
package com.stocknap;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


/*

This program prints even and odd sequence using two thread using samaphore

 */

public class Multithreading {
static Semaphore  lck  = new Semaphore(1,true);
static volatile AtomicInteger currThd = new AtomicInteger(0);
static  class evenThread implements  Runnable{

        Thread another;

        public void setAnother(Thread t){
            this.another =  t;
        }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(currThd.get() <= 10){

            if (currThd.get() % 2==0 ) {
                try {

                    lck.acquire();
                    System.out.println("acquiring lock by even thread "+another.getName());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(currThd);
                currThd.addAndGet(1);
                System.out.println("value increment by even thd "+another.getName());
                lck.release();
                System.out.println("lck released  by even thd "+another.getName());

            }


        }


    }



}

static class oddThread implements  Runnable{

    Thread another;

    public void setAnother(Thread t){
        this.another =  t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(currThd.get() < 10){

            if (currThd.get() % 2!=0  ) {
                try {

                    lck.acquire();
                    System.out.println("acquiring lock by odd thread "+another.getName());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(currThd);
                currThd.addAndGet(1);
                System.out.println("value increment by  odd thd "+another.getName());
                lck.release();
                System.out.println("lck released  by  odd  thd "+another.getName());

            }




        }



    }



}
public static void runFlow (String args[]){

    evenThread a = new evenThread();
    oddThread b = new oddThread();

    Thread t1 =  new Thread (a);
    Thread t2 =  new Thread ( b);
    a.setAnother(t2);
    b.setAnother(t1);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();



}
```

}

working with wait() and notify()

```
/*

This program prints even and odd sequence using two thread with intercommunication of wait and notify

 */


public class MultithreadingCommunication {

    static Semaphore lck  = new Semaphore(1,true);
    static volatile AtomicInteger currThd = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static  class evenThread implements  Runnable{

        String msg;

        public void setAnother(String t){
            this.msg =  t;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(currThd.get() < 10){

                synchronized (msg) {
                    if (currThd.get() % 2 == 0) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("acquiring lock by even thread");
                            lck.acquire();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println(currThd);
                        currThd.addAndGet(1);
                        System.out.println("value increment by thd");
                        lck.release();
                        System.out.println("lck released  by thd");
                        try {
                            msg.notify();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            msg.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            }


        }



    }

    static class oddThread implements  Runnable{

        String msg;

        public void setAnother(String t){
            this.msg =  t;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(currThd.get() <= 10){

                synchronized (msg){
                    if (currThd.get() % 2!=0  ) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("acquiring lock by odd thread");
                            lck.acquire();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println(currThd);
                        currThd.addAndGet(1);
                        lck.release();
                        try {
                            msg.notify();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        try {
                            msg.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }



            }



        }



    }
    public static void runFlow (String args[]){

        evenThread a = new evenThread();
        oddThread b = new oddThread();

        Thread t1 =  new Thread (a);
        Thread t2 =  new Thread ( b);

        String msg = "ok";
        a.setAnother(msg);
        b.setAnother(msg);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();



    }
}
```

Comment: If the exception is `IllegalMonitorStateException`, the problem is simple: you can call notify() and wait() on an object only when a thread executing these methods owns the monitor of the object. In simple words, you have to synchronize first before using the methods.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov thanks. Thats exactly the exception. Why i need separate synchronized block with wait and notify that i don't understand.

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` involves communication between threads. And this communication has to be properly synchronized, in order to prevent deadlocks. Imagine, what would happen if this case occures: 1. A thread checks a condition and invokes `wait()`. 2. Another thread sets the condition to true and invokes `notify()`. And it does it all right between the first thread's condition check and `wait()` invocation. 3. The first thread never gets the notifying message and never stops waiting. In order to prevent this case synchronization is needed.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov  I tried to use wait() and notify() using synchronized monitor as per your feedback now working fine so which one is better code without wait and notify having  less inter thread communication vs message passing using wait and notify but wasting more cpu cycles in while loop?

Comment: "without wait and notify" - if you're talking about Semaphore, thread synchronization is still done implicitly. I'd stick to Semaphore, because the code looks a bit clearer.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov can you up-vote some people find that discussion useful.